# R simple features: How do I create a square with sides of 20 km around a geographic coordinate?

Tags: r, r-sf

I am trying to use sf to create a square with each side equal to 10 km around a given midpoint. Right now, I am first creating a circle and then a square around it. I know st_buffer uses arc degrees and I would need to convert to km but I wanted to know if there's an easier/better way to create the square directly. Thanks!

```
# Create midpoint 
midpoint <-  st_point(c(38.29782, -76.51390))

# Turn it into a circle
circle <- midpoint %>% st_buffer(0.01)

# Turn the circle into a square
square <- circle %>% st_make_grid(n = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buffer the point 5km, and then use the bounding box of the circle.

```r
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

# Create midpoint 
midpoint <-  st_point(c(38.29782, -76.51390)) %>%
  st_sfc() %>%
  st_set_crs(4326)
# make a circular buffer w/5km radius
buf_round <- st_buffer(midpoint, dist = 5000)
# bounding box (square of the round buffer)
box_buf <- st_bbox(buf_round) %>%
  st_as_sfc() %>%
  st_as_sf()

# Length of one side of the box
box_buf %>%
  st_cast('LINESTRING') %>%
  st_length() / 4
#> 10146.44 [m]

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = midpoint, color = 'red') +
  geom_sf(data = buf_round, color = 'grey40', alpha = .2) +
  geom_sf(data = box_buf, fill = NA)
```

Only about 150m off per side. Maybe choose a different crs, or slightly smaller `st_buffer` size.
[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I found the espg conversion specific to the region I am using and that helped reduce the discrepancy on each side. Thanks!

Comment: @atatam_anukah Good to hear. I think web mercator (3857) would work too.